# Implementing push notifications in sails js

Tags: node.js, push-notification, sails.js, sails-mongo

I am new to sails js.
I want to implement push notifications for both android and IOS in sails js .

I am using Sails js with mongodb.

can anyone help me with regarding configuration or which plugin to use to implement push notifications in sails js.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

socket.io(the push notification library that sails uses) has [android](http://socket.io/blog/native-socket-io-and-android/) and [ios](http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-on-ios/) support. The only difference is, you can't use sails.io.js(sails's socket.io rest style client) as it's a javascript library. You should be able to just follow the docs for the android and ios libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [mosca](https://github.com/mcollina/mosca) It can be used to push the notifications. You would like to help. There is another similar programme [MQTT](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use [fcm-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-node) module.

You dont have to worry about the devices here. Its has a simple interface to Google's Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) & Supports both android and iOS, including topic messages, and parallel calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely suggest FCM-PUSH for your requirement. I have used and find it very easy to implement.

[NPM fcm-push](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fcm-push)

Steps which is provided in document is easily understandable. This will work for both ios and android. You just require firebase server key.

[Google Firebase](https://console.firebase.google.com/?pli=1)

I am finding for code. If I will get then post it in comment.